# Multi-part request using volley

Tags: android, post, android-volley, multipart

I have a multi-part request using Volley. First time I use this library and need to send an image to server and get an array in return. here is how I am doing it? Can you give any suggestions? I  worried about the structure if is done right. Thanks in advance. here is my code:
**I get ServerError**

```html
public MultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String mimeType, byte[] byteArray, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = errorListener;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
        this.mMimeType = mimeType;
        this.mMultipartBody = byteArray;
        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity() {
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("image", this.mMultipartBody,contentType, "image.jpg" );
        mHttpEntity = multipartEntity.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return  mHttpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            mHttpEntity.writeTo(bos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    }
    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {

        mListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

```html
 public void postImage(byte[] byteArray, VolleyResponseHandler volleyResponseHandler, final Context context) {


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(ApplicationConstants.BASE_URL, null, null, byteArray, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String result){
                    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("array");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                            listItems.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("error", error.toString());

                
        });

    multipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
```

This is the response i need to parse

```html
{
  “array”: [
    “one”,
    “two”,
    “three”
  ]
}
```

Comment: your code is working or not?

Comment: try this one [Android Volley Tutorial to Upload Image to Server](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/)

Comment: it's not working i get Servererror

Comment: Are there any server limitation like size (in KB) of picture or width and height?

Comment: yes, i compress the image before sending

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, this example is for sending image in Base64 string in raw body of http request. It won't work with multi-part. Also this tutorial is not good for performance based apps, as App will run out of memory.

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server,  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap. Use these two with retrofit if it is ok. Can't find better one for volley at the moment.